# Numba in nonpython mode is much slower than pure python (no print statements or specified numpy functions)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba, voronoi

I have recently discovered that Numba may work much slower than pure python even in non-python mode with the parrallel=True option enabled.
***Important**: If you don't deal with Voronoi diagrams please continue reading, my question doesn't relate to them directly.*
Currently, I am working on a problem where I have energy associated with the Voronoi diagram's edges and cells areas. The scipy Vornoi returns an array containing couples of points (vor.ridge_points) associated with each Vornoi edge. For my code, I want to have the ability to get index of the edge when providing indexes of the associated points, so I define a kind of adjacency matrix, but instead of ones and zeros, it has zeros and indexes of edges.
It turns out that **pure python when performing cycles over numpy arrays turns to be 10 times faster than numba**. Here is a toy example (i just randomly generated arrays, for the same number of edges and points as in my simulation).
My guess that it has something to do with memory allocation. Any take on the subject would be apprectiated (the reason why is it so much slower or a better way to get edge number from numbers of points) :)

```
# %%
from numba.np.ufunc import parallel
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from numba import prange

# %% generating array that models array og ridges
points_number = 8802
ridges_number = 26379

np.random.seed(123)
ridge_points = np.random.randint(points_number, size=(ridges_number, 2))

# %% symmetric matrix containing indexes of all edges
# in space [original_point_1, original_point_2]
ridge_points = np.array(ridge_points, dtype=np.int32)


@njit(parallel=True, cache=True)
def jit_edges_matrix_op(r_p, r_n):
    matrix = np.zeros((r_n, r_n), dtype=np.int32)

    for i in prange(r_n):
        e1 = r_p[i, 0]
        e2 = r_p[i, 1]
        matrix[e1, e2] = i
        matrix[e2, e1] = i

    return matrix


e_matrix_op = jit_edges_matrix_op(ridge_points, ridges_number)
# %% the same but not jitted


def edges_matrix_op(r_p, r_n):
    matrix = np.zeros((r_n, r_n), dtype=np.int32)

    for i in range(r_n):
        e1 = r_p[i, 0]
        e2 = r_p[i, 1]
        matrix[e1, e2] = i
        matrix[e2, e1] = i

    return matrix


e_matrix_op = edges_matrix_op(ridge_points, ridges_number)
# %%
%%timeit
jit_edges_matrix_op(ridge_points, ridges_number)
# %%
%%timeit
edges_matrix_op(ridge_points, ridges_number)
```

#### UPDATE

Indeed parallelization is not working properly here, so I run tests with parallel=False. Here are the results
630 ms ± 20.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) - parallel=True

553 ms ± 4.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) - parallel=False

66.5 ms ± 3.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) - pure python

#### UPDATE 2

Thanks to max9111 sharing a link https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7259
There seems to be an issue with allocating large arrays with zeros (np.zeros)
The issue has been reported a couple of weeks ago, and the link contains some workaround examples.

I tried allocating np.empty()

29.7 ms ± 1.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)- numba parallel=True

44.7 ms ± 2.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)- numba parallel=False

60.4 ms ± 1.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)- pure python

And as you can see **parallelized numba works the best**, so this task is parallizable and overhead is not that big

Comment: In both functions allocating matrix is by far the part which takes most of the time. Without that the timings are 0.5ms (Numba) and 17.5ms (Numpy). So it is all about creating the output array. There is already an issue here https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7259 Also also think that it is not intended here to use global variables (they can't be changed without recompilation in Numba). Looping over r_n would be a better idea.

Comment: Max, thanks for the reply. You are right about the use of the global variables, even though in this particular example, it doesn't affect performance, I fixed this issue. The link that you shared discusses precisely the allocation of np.zeros. I will try to allocate np.emty since later in my program i dont really use any other values of this matrix, aside from ones correposning to the edges.

Comment: @max9111 Added links and results of the tests to the main post. Could you please explain how did you manage to profile jitted function? just allocated array outside of numba and then passed it as an argument?

Comment: Yes I have allocated the memory outside and passed it to the jitted function. `def jit_edges_matrix_op(r_p, r_n,matrix):` and commenting out the memory allocation. The timings are only for the actual calculation and does not include memory allocation. BTW: You can easily replicate the way Numba does the memory allocation and zeroing also in numpy, if you call np.empty(...)  first and fill it with zeros afterwords. matrix[:,:]=0.

Comment: If you use parallel mode also check on a real world example. The parallelized function will be slower than the serial version on small problems and could be quite a lot slower if multiple threads write to the same cache line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the crucial issue is related to what is the nature of the calculations you are performing in this part of the code:

```
 for i in range(ridges_number):
        e1 = r_p[i, 0]
        e2 = r_p[i, 1]
        matrix[e1, e2] = i
        matrix[e2, e1] = i
```

Loop calculations are performing best if they are [cache-local](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/markusp/teaching/263-2300-ETH-spring14/slides/06-locality-caches.pdf) and trivially paralellizable (i.e. calculations are independent in each loop).

In your case, both of the conditions are violated. `e1` and `e2` do not take consecutive values across all of the loops. Similarly, the matrix `r_p` is likely preventing efficient paralellization because it needs to be accessed by all of the threads in each of the loops and probably it is locked by one while being accesed by all others).

All in all, the function you chose to speed-up may suffer the overhead of paralellization while in effect the calculations are executed sequentially. And the calculations, at least as they are at the moment, are inherently difficult to speed up by parallelization.

Comment: That makes sense, I have also run a test with not parallelized numba, here are the results on my machine:  
630 ms ± 20.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) - numba parallel=True |  
553 ms ± 4.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)  - numba  
parallel=False  |
66.5 ms ± 3.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) - pure python. It helped a little but numba is still about 10 times slower